# Resetting SMART on an SSD (hours powered on)

Tags: ssd, smart, drive-failure

We've been bitten by a known issue on SanDisk SSDs (Dell or HPE branded) where they hard fail after a certain number of hours powered on - 32768 or 40000 depending on the specific model.  Is there a reliable way to roll just this SMART attribute back so we can update firmware on these and get them running again?  We have many tools at our disposal but none that we know of that can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You cannot modify smart data.

Comment: yeah i'm thinking these are all paperweights now.  RIP

Answer (score 1):

In the following topic you'll see several tools to reset smart data in different flavours and colors.
I had the same question because I think I got a not-so "brand new" new drive. SMART looked ok, but was probably reset.
https://forum.hddguru.com/viewtopic.php?t=36754